# How to show alert for the empty input after preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase

I want to show a window alert if the input data is not filled in. However, the if-else statement in js file is not working. I guess it's because of 'preventDefault()', but I don't know how to handle this. Here is the condition for if and else.
if: store the data to database
else: show the alert

Here is my html file.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="trophyname" name="trophyname"><br>
</form>
```

And here is my javascript file.

```
if(trophyname){
  addBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    db.collection("efficacy").add({
    p_id: "T_001",
    trophyname : trophyname.value,
    time: time
      })
      .then(function() {
          alert('success');
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
      });
    });
}
else{
  alert('Fill in the blank');
}
```

Comment: You can add a `required` attribute to the input if you want to make sure that its been filled. `<input type="text" id="trophyname" name="trophyname" required>`

Comment: What is this `trophyname` variable? Please show the rest of your code, or at least enough to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The trophyname variable is here  
    var trophyname = document.getElementById("trophyname")